# Use Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first

Tags: python, pytorch

I am using the following code from [hgraph2graph](https://github.com/wengong-jin/hgraph2graph).
After the training starts I get the error message:

```
Epoch 0 training...
^M  0%|          | 0/13 [00:00<?, ?it/s]^M  0%|          | 0/13 [00:24<?, ?it/s]
....
TypeError: can't convert cuda:0 device type tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first.
```

I cannot figure out how to solve this although I have found some suggestions for similar issue. How should I modify this code to get away from the error.

Thanks,

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.optim.lr_scheduler as lr_scheduler
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

import rdkit
from rdkit import Chem, DataStructs
from rdkit.Chem import AllChem

import math, random, sys
import numpy as np
import argparse
import os
from tqdm.auto import tqdm

import hgraph
from hgraph import HierVAE, common_atom_vocab, PairVocab
from chemprop.train import predict
from chemprop.data import MoleculeDataset, MoleculeDataLoader
from chemprop.data.utils import get_data, get_data_from_smiles
from chemprop.utils import load_args, load_checkpoint, load_scalers

param_norm = lambda m: math.sqrt(sum([p.norm().item() ** 2 for p in m.parameters()]))
grad_norm = lambda m: math.sqrt(sum([p.grad.norm().item() ** 2 for p in 
m.parameters() if p.grad is not None]))


class Chemprop(object):

    def __init__(self, checkpoint_dir):
        self.features_generator = ['rdkit_2d_normalized']
        self.checkpoints, self.scalers, self.features_scalers = [], [], []
        for root, _, files in os.walk(checkpoint_dir):
            for fname in files:
                if fname.endswith('.pt'):
                    fname = os.path.join(root, fname)
                    scaler, features_scaler = load_scalers(fname)   
                    self.scalers.append(scaler)
                    self.features_scalers.append(features_scaler)
                    model = load_checkpoint(fname)
                    self.checkpoints.append(model)

    def predict(self, smiles, batch_size=500):
        test_data = get_data_from_smiles(
            smiles=[[s] for s in smiles],
            skip_invalid_smiles=False,
            features_generator=self.features_generator
        )
        valid_indices = [i for i in range(len(test_data)) if test_data[i].mol[0] is 
not None]
        full_data = test_data
        test_data = MoleculeDataset([test_data[i] for i in valid_indices])
        test_data_loader = MoleculeDataLoader(dataset=test_data, 
batch_size=batch_size)

        sum_preds = np.zeros((len(test_data), 1))
        for model, scaler, features_scaler in zip(self.checkpoints, self.scalers, 
self.features_scalers):
            test_data.reset_features_and_targets()
            if features_scaler is not None:
                test_data.normalize_features(features_scaler)

            model_preds = predict(
                model=model,
                data_loader=test_data_loader,
                scaler=scaler
            )
            sum_preds += np.array(model_preds)

        # Ensemble predictions
        avg_preds = sum_preds / len(self.checkpoints)
        avg_preds = avg_preds.squeeze(-1).tolist()

        # Put zero for invalid smiles
        full_preds = [0.0] * len(full_data)
        for i, si in enumerate(valid_indices):
            full_preds[si] = avg_preds[i]

        return np.array(full_preds, dtype=np.float32)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    lg = rdkit.RDLogger.logger() 
    lg.setLevel(rdkit.RDLogger.CRITICAL)

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--train', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--vocab', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--atom_vocab', default=common_atom_vocab)
    parser.add_argument('--save_dir', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--generative_model', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--chemprop_model', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--seed', type=int, default=7)

    parser.add_argument('--rnn_type', type=str, default='LSTM')
    parser.add_argument('--hidden_size', type=int, default=250)
    parser.add_argument('--embed_size', type=int, default=250)
    parser.add_argument('--batch_size', type=int, default=20)
    parser.add_argument('--latent_size', type=int, default=32)
    parser.add_argument('--depthT', type=int, default=15)
    parser.add_argument('--depthG', type=int, default=15)
    parser.add_argument('--diterT', type=int, default=1)
    parser.add_argument('--diterG', type=int, default=3)
    parser.add_argument('--dropout', type=float, default=0.0)

    parser.add_argument('--lr', type=float, default=1e-3)
    parser.add_argument('--clip_norm', type=float, default=5.0)
    parser.add_argument('--epoch', type=int, default=10)
    parser.add_argument('--inner_epoch', type=int, default=10)
    parser.add_argument('--threshold', type=float, default=0.3)
    parser.add_argument('--min_similarity', type=float, default=0.1)
    parser.add_argument('--max_similarity', type=float, default=0.5)
    parser.add_argument('--nsample', type=int, default=10000)

    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args)

    torch.manual_seed(args.seed)
    random.seed(args.seed)

    with open(args.train) as f:
        train_smiles = [line.strip("\r\n ") for line in f]

    vocab = [x.strip("\r\n ").split() for x in open(args.vocab)] 
    args.vocab = PairVocab(vocab)

    score_func = Chemprop(args.chemprop_model)
    good_smiles = train_smiles
    train_mol = [Chem.MolFromSmiles(s) for s in train_smiles]
    train_fps = [AllChem.GetMorganFingerprintAsBitVect(x, 2, 2048) for x in 
train_mol]

    model = HierVAE(args).cuda()
    optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=args.lr)

    print('Loading from checkpoint ' + args.generative_model)
    model_state, optimizer_state, _, beta = torch.load(args.generative_model)
    model.load_state_dict(model_state)
    optimizer.load_state_dict(optimizer_state)

    for epoch in range(args.epoch):
        good_smiles = sorted(set(good_smiles))
        random.shuffle(good_smiles)
        dataset = hgraph.MoleculeDataset(good_smiles, args.vocab, args.atom_vocab, 
args.batch_size)

        print(f'Epoch {epoch} training...')
        for _ in range(args.inner_epoch):
            meters = np.zeros(6)
            dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=1, collate_fn=lambda x:x[0], 
shuffle=True, num_workers=16)
            for batch in tqdm(dataloader):
                model.zero_grad()
                loss, kl_div, wacc, iacc, tacc, sacc = model(*batch, beta=beta)
                loss.backward()
                nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), args.clip_norm)
                optimizer.step()
                meters = meters + np.array([kl_div, loss.item(), wacc * 100, iacc * 
100, tacc * 100, sacc * 100])

            meters /= len(dataset)
            print("Beta: %.3f, KL: %.2f, loss: %.3f, Word: %.2f, %.2f, Topo: %.2f, 
Assm: %.2f, PNorm: %.2f, GNorm: %.2f" % (beta, meters[0], meters[1], meters[2], 
meters[3], meters[4], meters[5], param_norm(model), grad_norm(model)))

        ckpt = (model.state_dict(), optimizer.state_dict(), epoch, beta)
        torch.save(ckpt, os.path.join(args.save_dir, f"model.ckpt.{epoch}"))

        print(f'Epoch {epoch} decoding...')
        decoded_smiles = []
        with torch.no_grad():
            for _ in tqdm(range(args.nsample // args.batch_size)):
                outputs = model.sample(args.batch_size, greedy=True)
                decoded_smiles.extend(outputs)

        print(f'Epoch {epoch} filtering...')
        scores = score_func.predict(decoded_smiles)
        outputs = [(s,p) for s,p in zip(decoded_smiles, scores) if p >= 
args.threshold]
        print(f'Discovered {len(outputs)} active molecules')

        novel_entries = []
        good_entries = []
        for s, p in outputs:
            mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles(s)
            fps = AllChem.GetMorganFingerprintAsBitVect(mol, 2, 2048)
            sims = np.array(DataStructs.BulkTanimotoSimilarity(fps, train_fps))
            good_entries.append((s, p, sims.max()))
            if args.min_similarity <= sims.max() <= args.max_similarity:
                novel_entries.append((s, p, sims.max()))
                good_smiles.append(s)

    print(f'Discovered {len(novel_entries)} novel active molecules')
    with open(os.path.join(args.save_dir, f"new_molecules.{epoch}"), 'w') as f:
        for s, p, sim in novel_entries:
            print(s, p, sim, file=f)

    with open(os.path.join(args.save_dir, f"good_molecules.{epoch}"), 'w') as f:
        for s, p, sim in good_entries:
            print(s, p, sim, file=f)
```

Comment: why is this tagged tensorflow if you are using pytorch

Answer (score 0):

This error is thrown at this line :

```
meters = meters + np.array([kl_div, loss.item(), wacc * 100, iacc * 
100, tacc * 100, sacc * 100])
```

That's because `wacc, iacc, tacc, sacc` are still on cuda, and casting them to an `np.array` directly throws this error. Replace them with `wacc.item()` (similar to how you're doing it with `loss`) to cast into the numpy array.

Comment: Thanks @Suraj813, changing the following line solved the problem .meters = meters + np.array([kl_div, loss.item(), wacc.cpu() * 100, iacc.cpu() * 100, tacc.cpu() * 100, sacc.cpu() * 100])